# WCF service callback not called

Tags: c#, wcf

I am using tcp binding in WCF service and my callback at client side in not getting called.This is my code

Service

```
 public interface IMyContractCallback
{
   [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]  
    void OnCallback();
}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof (IMyContractCallback),SessionMode =
 SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IService1
{

     [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]  
    void DoSomething();      


      [OperationContract]
    int GetCount();
}

 public class Service1 : IService1
{

    private int count=0;   
    public int GetCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        count++;
        Console.WriteLine("increased count");
       IMyContractCallback callback =  
                 OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyContractCallback>();

            if ((callback as IChannel).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
                callback.OnCallback();
            }

    }       
}
```

and my client is

```
public class App1
{


    private MyServiceCallback callback;
    private InstanceContext context;
    private Service1Client proxy;       

    public App1()
    {
        callback=new MyServiceCallback();


        context = new InstanceContext(callback);
        var factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IService1>(callback, "EndPointTCP");
        IService1 proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

        callback.proxy = proxy;

        proxy.DoSomething();


    }
}

public class MyServiceCallback : IService1Callback
{

    public IService1 proxy
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public void OnCallback()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Callback thread = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetCount());

    }
}
```

I face two issues:

1.I dont receive callback from DoSomething with above mentioned code.
2.If I declare DoSomething as Twoway ,I do receive callback but it throws exception  "Server did not provide a meaningful reply"

My client config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="EndPointTCP" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                transactionFlow="false"
                transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
                 maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:20:00"
                    enabled="true" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
        <wsDualHttpBinding>
            <binding name="EndPointHTTP" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
                   maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                           negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="masked"
            binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EndPointHTTP"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="EndPointHTTP">
            <identity>
                <servicePrincipalName value="masked" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="masked"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EndPointTCP"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="EndPointTCP">
            <identity>
                <servicePrincipalName value="masked" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
```

my Service config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>


<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" />

 </system.web>

<system.diagnostics>
 <sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel"
          switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
          propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData= "d:\log\Traces.svclog" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
 </sources>
 </system.diagnostics>

 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="TcpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  
       maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" portSharingEnabled="true" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport"/>
      <reliableSession enabled="true" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfService2.MyServiceBehaviour" 
   name="WcfService2.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="EndPointHTTP" contract="WcfService2.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TcpBinding"
      name="EndPointTCP" contract="WcfService2.IService1" isSystemEndpoint="false" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="mexpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WcfService2.MyServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"  />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="10000"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true" showFlags="Date, Time, Size, Extension, LongDate" />
  </system.webServer>

  </configuration>
```

Comment: I think the title of your question is misleading. The last paragraph indicates that you do get the callback; the real issue is why `GetCount()` is failing. Would you agree?

Comment: As a first step toward troubleshooting, I would try changing `SessionMode.Required` to `SessionMode.Allowed`. I would also move `DeRegister` into the callback handler; this will allow you to put `IsOneWay` back on `DoSomething()`.

Comment: could you plz share your service and client config file's serviceModel part.

Comment: @Jay What I meant in last paragraph is that I only get callback if I declare DoSomething() as two way operation ,I dont get callback when it is one way and if I declare as two way,I get callback but the callback completes with an exception "Server did not provide a meaningful reply" irrespective of the fact if I call Getcount or not inside callback.So my question is first why my one way operation not returning callbacks and second why Iam getting exception in callback from a two way operation.I tried with SessionMode.Allowed also ,,still same issue presists.

Comment: @Adarsh I added client and service configs.

Comment: @Everybody  I have modified the code and problem statement to refine my issue.

Comment: are you able to debug whether callback.OnCallback(); is really executed?

Comment: @rudolf_franek yes,Iam able to hit a breakpoint in callback when DoSomething is defined as two way but again it ends with an exception mentioned in my problem statement,but with one way I dont hit the same breakpoint.

Comment: @TRS Did you also move `DeRegister()` into the callback handler? I believe that calling that immediately after `DoSomething()` is what is preventing this from working when `DoSomething()` has the `IsOneWay` attribute set. I don't think you should exclude that code from the question; it is important to the overall issue.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, you're calling the service again from the callback. If you would leave this out, there's no error about "no meaningful answer".

It should help to set ConcurrencyMode attribute to your service and callback class:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class Service1 : IService1
...
```

and

```
[CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class MyServiceCallback : IService1Callback
...
```

You must set "IsOneWay = false" in the OperationContract, of course.

Comment: Thats not the solution,even if I dont call service again from callback I still get the "no meaningful reply error" and also could you please elaborate on "You must set "IsOneWay = false" in the OperationContract, of course." I am sure we can have callbacks from one way operations also but somehow not working in my case.

Comment: "The problem is, you're calling the service again from the callback" - it is good point

Comment: Well, I could reproduce what you've described, until I set ConcurrencyMode or remove the GetCount call. OTOH, I don't have your original project. Can it be downloaded somewhere? Callbacks don't work with "IsOneWay=true". It may be, however, that it is implied as soon as callbacks are used.

Comment: It would be interesting indeed to see your real project, because as it stands the code above lacks a base address. In my test I used a WCFService library and a console client. I had to add the base address though.

Answer (score 1):

It should work using IsOneWay = true..

Here is an example

----Service Code

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IServerFinishedProcessingCallback), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IDualMathService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void ProcessAdd(double num1, double num2);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ProcessSubtract(double num1, double num2);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void ProcessMultiply(double num1, double num2);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void ProcessDivide(double num1, double num2);
}            
public interface IServerFinishedProcessingCallback
{        
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void ProcessingFinished(string operation, double result);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class DualMathServiceClass : IDualMathService
{
    readonly IServerFinishedProcessingCallback _clientCode = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IServerFinishedProcessingCallback>();
    //[PrincipalPermission()]
    public void ProcessAdd(double num1, double num2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing Request for client session ID " + OperationContext.Current.SessionId);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Processing Add Request for parameters {0} and {1} ", num1, num2));
        _clientCode.ProcessingFinished("Add", (num1 + num2));
    }
    public void ProcessSubtract(double num1, double num2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing Request for client session ID " + OperationContext.Current.SessionId);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Processing Subtract Request for parameters {0} and {1} ", num1, num2));
        _clientCode.ProcessingFinished("Subtract", (num1 - num2));
    }
    public void ProcessMultiply(double num1, double num2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing Request for client session ID " + OperationContext.Current.SessionId);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Processing Multiply Request for parameters {0} and {1} ", num1, num2));
        _clientCode.ProcessingFinished("Multiply", (num1 * num2));
    }
    public void ProcessDivide(double num1, double num2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing Request for client session ID " + OperationContext.Current.SessionId);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Processing Divide Request for parameters {0} and {1} ", num1, num2));
        if (num2 == 0)
            throw new FaultException<string>("Number 2 can not be zer");
        _clientCode.ProcessingFinished("Divide", (num1 / num2));
    }
}
```

---

Client Code

```
[CallbackBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true,
    UseSynchronizationContext = true,
    ValidateMustUnderstand =true,
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class ClientCallbackClass : IDualMathServiceCallback
{
    public delegate void ProceFinishedEventDelegate(string operation, double result);
    public event ProceFinishedEventDelegate ProcessFinishedEvent = null;
    public void ProcessingFinished(string operation, double result)
    {            
        if (ProcessFinishedEvent != null)
        {
            ProcessFinishedEvent(operation, result);
        }
    }
}
```